# Make mod menus consistent regarding disabled options

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, spam

Currently, if an action in a mod menu isn't available (like "show deleted comments" for a post with no deleted comments), it gets greyed out/disabled, in *most* cases. Today I learned about this option:

[image: enter link description here]

I never knew it existed (I don't think most of the mods know of this either--I know that at least one comm team member doesn't know), because I'd never seen it before. We can't really use tools that we don't know exist, till now I believed that this was impossible. <sup>1</sup>

This UI seems inconsistent to me -- some options get greyed out when available, some just disappear.

Could this be changed so that *all* "currently unavailable" options (not sure if there are any more) are displayed and greyed out on their mod menus?

<sup>1 A few days ago, a mod who was in need of this feature to fix a mistaken spam-bomb received bad advice in TL from me and others since nobody knew of this feature. In the end, I think he compensated the user via a bounty.</sup>

Comment: Never knew about that. It shows up in mod menus on posts that have been locked as spam? Have outstanding spam flags?

Comment: @DoubleAA: Not sure. I think it's both.

Comment: Oh I see it now. Cool.

Answer (score 4):

I want the UI to be consistent, but I don't like the idea of having all items visible all the time. There are at least 14 different items if you count both the answer-only and the question-only ones; at least 11 that can apply to ansers and at least 12 that can apply to questions.

So I'd prefer to see only the applicable items, with some way to discover all possibilities. Like a “show disabled items” checkbox, maybe? Even better, link to some documentation (which could be a community-maintained MSO post) for each item, at least for the more obscure ones.

In the absence of such a list, here are the available items (please update if I've forgotten some). Some of them are only applicable to questions (protect, merge, …) or only to answers (convert to comment/edit, …), some only in particular circumstances (clear spam/offensive flags, see deleted comments, …).

- protect
- add post notice (“citation needed”, “current event” or “insufficient explanation”)
- convert to wiki (i.e. make community wiki)
- remove wiki
- show *N* deleted comments
- merge (to move all of a question's answers to a duplicate)
- clear migration history
- lock/unlock
- purge all comments
- convert to comment
- convert to edit (on a self-answer)
- clear offensive/spam flags
- show flag history
- show review history

And while we're at it, it would be nice if the order made sense. And if it was consistent between questions and answers!

Comment: What is 'clear migration history'?

Comment: @DoubleAA On a migrated question, break the connection between the original and the copy. This can be used on either the source or the destination site. After that the questions are independent, as if they had been posted separately. It's one of those tools that are used rarely. An example use case is when a question was migrated in error, the source site wants to reopen it, but the target site has additional answers that it wants to keep.